# How can I Implement sql search functionality in a Stored procedure (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure that will search a table based on optional parameters Using sql server 2008.

There will be two modes

- basic search mode (we just pass some text)
- advanced search mode (Optional parameters are used NOT SearchText is used.)

  For testing I am using the AdventureWorks.Person.Contact table

  Would you write something like below **if not** can you make suggestions how to improve it?
  Thanks a lot

  ```
  ALTER PROCEDURE SearchPeople
  @SearchText nvarchar(200)=NULL,   --- only used in basic search mode
  @SearchMode bit,
  @FirstName varchar(50)=NULL,
  @LastName varchar(50)=NULL,
  @EmailAddress varchar(50)=NULL,
  @Phone nvarchar(25)=NULL
  ```

AS

```
IF @SearchMode=0
    BEGIN   
    print 'BASIC SEARCH'
        SELECT *
        FROM   [Person].[Contact] 
        WHERE  (FirstName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' 
        OR LastName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
        OR EmailAddress LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
        OR Phone LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%')

    END

ELSE
   BEGIN    

    print 'ADVANCED SEARCH'

        SELECT *
        FROM   [Person].[Contact] 
        WHERE  (FirstName =@FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL) 
        AND (LastName =@LastName OR @FirstName IS NULL) 
        AND (EmailAddress =@EmailAddress OR @EmailAddress IS NULL) 
        AND (Phone =@Phone OR @Phone IS NULL) 

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joe. Your solution would lead to parameter sniffing. one way to solve param sniffing is to split into basic and advance search stored procedure. But even then you would need to use Dynamic SQL in the advanced search stored procedure to avoid parameter sniffing. I dont know about your specific situation, but if you have just one or two fields to search by, then maybe you dont need to worry about param sniffing, but if you have , lets say, more than 5 or 6 parameters you should definitely go with dynamic SQL.

so the advanced search should look something like this.

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = 'SELECT *
              FROM [Person].[Contact]
              WHERE 1=1 '

IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL 
 SET @query = @query + ' AND FirstName = @FirstName '  

IF @LastName IS NOT NULL 
 SET @query = @query + ' AND LastName = @LastName '  

IF @EmailAddress IS NOT NULL 
 SET @query = @query + ' AND EmailAddress = @EmailAddress '  

IF @Phone IS NOT NULL 
 SET @query = @query + ' AND Phone = @Phone ' 

sp_executesql @query, 
              N'@FirstName VARCHAR(50),
                @LastName VARCHAR(50),
                @EmailAddress VARHCAR(50),
                @Phone NVARCHAR(25)',
              @FirstName,
              @LastName,
              @EmailAddress,
              @Phone
```

Here is a usefull article on parameter sniffing [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316195523/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx)

Comment: @Sadhir: Yes. In comments on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138227/how-can-i-implement-sql-search-functionality-in-a-stored-procedure-sql-server-2/4138273#4138273), I just pointed the OP to Gail Shaw's blog post on [catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) to help him understand the problems around his advance search technique.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Bit rusty on the sql side .Couple of questions  what does "where 1=1 do? also I see you are building a query  how do you execute it at the end? I need to search by 6 params exactly.Thanks for your help

Comment: yeah just saw your comment. That looks like a great blog post. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: @user - 'where 1=1' doesnt do anything - it is a condition that will always evaluate to true. It is just there so that if all the parameters are NULL i would still have a valid query. 

And you are right. I forgot to include the execution part. I will add it to my answer in a while

Comment: Is Contains better than Like?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd split the basic and advance search out into two separate procedures, and I'd give serious consideration to implementing [fulltext searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) for your basic search.

Comment: Is the sql correct I mean the use of IsNull and Like operator ?   They dont use FullText search in my office.Does the Sql Server standard edition provide FullText. If I were to use as it is could this be improved

Comment: Your SQL is looks syntactically correct. See Gail Shaw's blog post on [catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) to understand some problems your advanced search technique may encounter. Fulltext searching is available in Standard edition. You'll need to read up on it to see if it will work in your specific situation, but it should perform significantly better than a `LIKE '%text%'` search.